# metro style on windows and android

Tags: android, ios, windows, metro

I want to develop a rather simple app using windows 8 metro style for GUI. But i need this app to have the same appearance, GUI, for both platforms, so that end users that uses it both on PC and a mobile device to have the same visual experience and a flawless navigation.

So, does anyone have knowledge of a Java framework or library to satisfy these needs? Or maybe a method to create a web-based app using HTML, PHP, JScript etc. (maybe something using a local server, on the same machine, because a web server is out of discussion, at least for the moment)? Any idea, method, technology related to the subject is also helpful. And if what you are thinking at can be used for IOS too, the better.

Comment: _"does anyone have knowledge of a Java framework or library..."_ -- Questions asking us to recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Programmers as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Well, sorry for that! I was looking for a place on the Stack platform where to ask for advices like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were to write a metro themed application on android, I'd probably see if I couldn't write  the equivalent in html and try to build an android application from that html page.

I noticed that [Android does support the concept of web pages being shown](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html).  Combine this with [metro js](http://jquer.in/responsive/metro-js/) which should greatly simplify your task towards making a metro themed web page and what you have is the workings of a perfectly functional android web application that would be easy to fix and could probably be ported to other devices quite easily as well.

However this is my approach.  You mentioned html and javascript, and so I assume you have some basic knowledge of these technologies.  If not, now is as good a time as any to learn.

Just a tip for you though, make sure the web application looks proper at low resolutions before porting it to android.  It will probably save you time.

Comment: Well, my knowledge is mostly in Java and C++, but i know a bit of HTML, PHP. A web solution was my first thought, but i don't know if a local server can be implemented on android, and what (if there are any) limitations are.

Comment: @MRM I think the sky is the limit.  Assuming your application has internet permission, you can view a web page like you were browsing on your android phone.  Of course I see that on the page of the link I wrote regarding the WebView, you can communicate easily to the web application by doing things like `Android.showToast(toast)`.  Obviously the more you use this, the less compatibile it would be on other platforms.  I would be  mindful of that and perhaps try to push all such methods into a single object so that you could swap it later.